# Mostrar opcion multiple en ejs

Tags: html, nodejs, bootstrap, ejs

tengo el siguiente codigo en mi template:

```
 <form action="/alumno/inicio/<%= prueba.id %>/pregunta1" method="POST">
            <div class="mt-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="p1respuesta" name="p1respuesta">
                    <option value=1><%= prueba.p1opcion1 %></option>
                    <option value=2><%= prueba.p1opcion2 %></option>
                    <option value=3><%= prueba.p1opcion3 %></option>
                    <option value=4><%= prueba.p1opcion4 %></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                    Siguiente
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

El cual me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente al hacerle click al campo salen las demás opciones, y al hacerle click al botón siguiente me guarda la opción que esta seleccionada, sin embargo este formato no es el que quiero, solo lo hice para comprobar funcionalidades, el que quiero es algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he buscado en la documentación de bootstrap y no aparece, no tengo idea de como hacerlo, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes usar campos de input normales (con el tipo checkbox supongo, o de radio si solo es una opción la que pueden elegir), maquetados con CSS, y compartiendo el mismo name pero en forma de array, es decir, `name=p1respuesta[]`.  Por cierto, tu select **no** es multiple.

Comment: exacto, lo hice para que solo se pueda escoger una opcion de las 4

Comment: pues cambia el título de la pregunta, es confuso así

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, puse lo siguiente:

```
<form action="/alumno/inicio/<%= prueba.id %>/pregunta1" method="POST">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value=1 name="p1respuesta"><%= prueba.p1opcion1 %>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value=2 name="p1respuesta"><%= prueba.p1opcion2 %>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value=3 name="p1respuesta"><%= prueba.p1opcion3 %>
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value=4 name="p1respuesta"><%= prueba.p1opcion4 %>
            </label>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                    Siguiente
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Me sale para que se escoja una de las 4 opciones y se guarda la que escogi, solo tendria que cambiarle el formato a tipo botones

Comment: Acostúmbrate a poner el value entre comillas... todos los atributos en HTML las llevan aunque sean numéricos

Comment: es que en la BD me lo lee asi, ya que lo puse como integer

Comment: Tu backend lo recibirá igualmente como número aunque lo pongas entrecomillado en el HTML. Es un formulario.  Pruébalo para salir de dudas, pero vamos, yo no tengo duda ninguna a menos que tu aplicativo se lea el HTML directamente de algún modo inusual, pero si son datos que se envian por formulario o por javascript debería funcionar bien entrecomillado.